# What is FIND call in request?

Tags: rest, http, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert a curl call to python request . The curl call looks like

```
$ curl -b $COOKIE_FILE \
-X FIND $URL \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
```

I tried using request to get the correct response via **requests.post()** but i could not get the correct response. Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests allows using arbitrary request methods with the `request` function, take a look at the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/api/).

For example this is how it would look with a Session() object:

```py
import requests
with requests.Session() as sess:
    sess.headers = {
        #headers in dict format, you could add cookies here too(or set it to sess.cookies)
    }
    response = sess.request("FIND", url)
```